# Elaborate the usage and meaning of "fly-on-the-wall account" -- Full sentence in the description

Tags: meaning, usage

> Donald Trump reacted angrily to a fly-on-the-wall account of his first
>   nine months in the White House.

- Taken from The Economist 19th January 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiom is pretty straightforward, at least, once someone explains it to you.  Imagine you're a housefly resting on the wall of Donald Trump's office.  You don't participate in anything that goes on; you just watch and remember what you saw.

That's what is meant by "a fly on the wall account".  The author of the book quietly sat in on various meetings in the White House, but wasn't a direct participant.  He then wrote his version of what he observed.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate you taking the time for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

In literature, a fly-on-the-wall narrative is another name for the third-person, objective, point of view. The narrator reports only what is observable in the physical world, in contrast to, for example, the third-person, omniscient, point of view, where the narrator might also tell you what people are thinking or feeling.